# How to prevent PyMySQL from escaping identifier names?

Tags: python, mysql, string-formatting, pymysql, python-db-api

I am utilizing PyMySQL with Python **2.7** and try to execute the following statement:

```
'INSERT INTO %s (%s, %s) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE %s = %s'
```

With the following parameters:

```
('artikel', 'REC_ID', 'odoo_created', u'48094', '2014-12-23 10:00:00', 'odoo_modified', '2014-12-23 10:00:00')
```

Always resulting in:

> {ProgrammingError}(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''artikel' ('REC_ID', 'odoo_created')\n
>   VALUES ('48094', '2014-12-' at line 1")

Which seems to me like PyMySQL is escaping all strings during formatting. How can I prevent that for database identifiers like table and column names? It corrupts the statement, since `SELECT`s from string literals (`SELECT * FROM "table"`) are not possible in comparison to tables (`SELECT * FROM table`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the point of DB API's substitution. It escapes values. You really shouldn't need to escape table/column names.

I'd use something like:

```
execute('''INSERT INTO {} ({}, {}) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {} = %s'''
    .format('artikel', 'REC_ID', 'odoo_created', 'odoo_modified'),
    (u'48094', '2014-12-23 10:00:00', '2014-12-23 10:00:00')
)
```

Or, you know, just write the names directly.

Comment: Results in `TypeError` stating not all arguments converted during string formatting. My conversion attempt of the unicode string did not solve the problem. Writing the table name in the literal is not an option since the table name can be different on every invocation. [PEP 249 does not list new-style parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) as valid.

Comment: @Alomvar My code can't cause such an error. You made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: The braces (`{}`) do not work for me in Python 2.7. A simple test of `"herp {}" % ("derp")` in the command line yields the same result. It does work with `%s` though.

Comment: @Alomvar Okay, you made a mistake. `"{}".format` and `"%s"%` are different things.

Comment: Yes, now I see (WTF didn't I see that earlier?!). I also found the reason for the `TypeError` issues: in one stack frame arguments get crammed into a tuple because of `*args` usage.

Comment: You do need to escape column names if they come from a user. For example `ORDER BY {sort}'.format(sort=sort)` coming from a URL like `?sort=foo`.

Comment: "you shouldn't be doing this" sometimes **isn't** the answer you're looking for.